# Can an unnamed struct be made static?

Tags: c++, static, unnamed-class

Can you make an unnamed struct a static member of a class?

```
struct Foo
{
    struct namedStruct
    {
        int memb1, memb2;
    };
    static namedStruct namedStructObj;
    struct
    {
        int memb1, memb2;
    } unnamedStructObj;
};

Foo::namedStruct Foo::namedStructObj;
// The unnamed type doesn't seem to have a type you can write
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
struct Foo
{
    struct
    {
        int memb1, memb2;
    } static unnamedStructObj;
};

decltype(Foo::unnamedStructObj) Foo::unnamedStructObj;
```

Here, as you don't have any way to reference the unnamed struct, using `decltype(Foo::unnamedStructObj)` makes it possible to retrieve the type of `Foo::unnamedStructObj`, so you can write the definition.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with the help of `decltype()`:

```
struct Foo
{
    struct namedStruct
    {
        int memb1, memb2;
    };
    static namedStruct namedStructObj;
    static struct
    {
        int memb1, memb2;
    } unnamedStructObj;
};

Foo::namedStruct Foo::namedStructObj;
decltype(Foo::unnamedStructObj) Foo::unnamedStructObj;
```